# Sharepoint Library folders Permissions issue

Tags: sharepoint, shared-libraries, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a sharepoint Library 'World'.In World library,there are multiple country folders and in each country folders we have different cities.

My requirement is that only certain group(ADMIN,SUPER ADMIN) have access on all folders and sub-folders and then only groups having same name as of Cities having access on cities folders(in country).

Now what I did is I have stopped inheritance of World Library and added to user X to City 'Washington' Group and 'Washington' group has access on 'Washington' folder that is within USA folder.

Issue is when user X trying to browse Washington folder,access denied is coming.

Comment: is user x able to view list and USA folder? or user x is getting error on accessing list?

Comment: Access denied while browsing list

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested folders on a document library, each of the permission groups need at least read access at the top level of the library to be able to browse to their folder. The only work around is to provide them with a direct link to their folder, but in some cases I've found that any modifications to their folder - even with full edit permissions will error out if they don't have read access to the top level of the list.

See this question and answer here > https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/855f2c2d-3b7f-416a-907b-ec6b434665e0/folder-permissions-with-nested-folder?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious